# associate a custom file extension with my java program on windows

Tags: java, installation

is there a way to associate a custom file extension with my java program on windows?  I have installAnywhere to create an installer.  But I'm not sure how this can be done if it's possible. Every installer on window does this, but what if it's in Java.  I imagine it would require registry modification by the installer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [Launch4j](http://launch4j.sourceforge.net/). It allows you to wrap your java application into a native Windows .exe file, with which it should be trivial to associate a custom file extension.

Last time I dealt with InstallAnywhere was back when it was made by ZeroG, so I don't quite remember how it's done there. I'm using  [Nullsoft Install System](http://nsis.sourceforge.net) now which has a convenient [macro](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/File_Association) to register file extensions, I'm sure InstallAnywhere has a similar facility.

Comment: I ended up using Advanced installer since it has a very simple gui for making all these: file assoc, exe conversion,etc